# I am looking for menu on JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, user-interface, menu

May be some body already used some open source component, writing on jquery. And I want to place this menu on right panel of my site.

Thanks to advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check [this](http://www.developerfox.com/13-excellent-tutorials-on-creating-jquery-navigation-menu/584) or [this](http://www.ajaxline.com/10-best-jquery-menu-plugins) or lots of other examples in Google.

Comment: the second ling was useful for me

Answer (score 0):

There you go:
http://www.noupe.com/jquery/35-fresh-useful-jquery-plugins.html

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Superfish](http://users.tpg.com.au/j_birch/plugins/superfish).